# Trying to find a function from line length

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, line-integrals

I was wondering if it was possible to find a function $f(x)$ whose line length is equal to its integral, thinking about it logically the function $f(x)=1$ satisfies these conditions as the line length is just equal to $x$ and so is the antiderivative, However I was wondering if there could be any more functions that satisfy this, that is to say:
$$\int\sqrt{1+f'^2}\,dx=\int f\,dx$$
Which I think is fair to change to:
$$\sqrt{1+f'^2}=f$$
$$1+f'^2(x)=f^2(x)$$
Any suggestions?

Comment: I note that $f(x) = \cosh x$ is one solution to the differential equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{df}{dx} = \pm \sqrt{f^2-1},\\
\frac{df}{\sqrt{f^2-1}} = \pm dx,\qquad\text{if $f\neq1$}\\
\frac{d(\cosh u)}{\sqrt{\cosh^2 u-1}} = \pm dx,\qquad f = \cosh u, \\
|u|=C\pm x,\\
f=\cosh(C\pm x) = \cosh(x+C).
$$

So there are two solution $f_1=\cosh(x+C)$ and $f_2=1$. They can transform into each other at points where $f_1=f_2=1$, which for function $f_1$ happens only at one point $x=-C$, so a general solution is:

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}\cosh(x-a), &x\le a,\\
1,&a<x<b,\\
\cosh(x-b),& x\ge b\end{cases}
$$

where $b\ge a$ are constants.